# Is it possible to make a class which lets you stack enum Flags?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, boolean-operations, enum-flags

I'd like to use named constants whereever possible instead of providing literal values or longish function signatures with a lot of boolean args.

Therefore i like pythons `enum.Flag` or `enum.Enum`.

More precisely, I would like to pass an argument to a function which holds a bit combination of enum.Flags. And i would like to avoid writing `module.TheFlags.flagX` for every set flag I would like to pass to the function. The flags should replace the boolean args.

I came up with following code:

```
import enum


class AvailableFlags(enum.Flag):
    flag1 = enum.auto()
    flag2 = enum.auto()


class FuncFlags:
    def __init__(self):
        self._flags = AvailableFlags(0)

    @property
    def flag1(self):
        self._flags |= AvailableFlags.flag1
        return self

    @property
    def flag2(self):
        self._flags |= AvailableFlags.flag2
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._flags.value)


def func(setup_flags: FuncFlags):
    print(setup_flags)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func(FuncFlags().flag1)
    func(FuncFlags().flag2)
    func(FuncFlags().flag1.flag2)
    func(FuncFlags())
```

It creates instances of FuncFlags and then *mis-uses* the properties to set single flags returning the changed object itself.
However, one would expect that the property does NOT change object state.
Therefore, this is obviously not a clean solution despite that it works, though.

So, my question is, how this can be implemented in a clean, reusable way?

Comment: If that's the purpose of the helper class, I wouldn't call it "misuse". Note that you could implement `__getattr__` to avoid hardcoding every flag into `FuncFlags`. Another option would be to pass flags as strings such as `FuncFlags() | 'flag1' | 'flag2'`. But this doesn't support IDE inspection. I guess the cleanest solution would be to use a shorthand name, such as `F = module.TheFlags; func(F.flag1 | F.flag2)`.

Comment: Yes, OK. Done. But i see another pitfall: `ff = FuncFlags(); func(ff.flag1); func(ff.flag2)` yields consequently `1 3`. However, it would be desired it returns `1 2`. Don't know howto prevent people from using an instance again and again instead of always creating a new instance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you are trying to avoid?

Comment: E.g. boolean args: `def func(flag1:bool = False, flag2:bool = True, ....)` and even when i use only one flag at the moment this may change in future, so boolean args are not really maintainable. The alternative of passing an `int` is out of question, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found an answer by adding another level of indirection.
I want to share it here if it is of interest for someone else.
Object state is maintained as every invokation of a flag creates a new instance from the current instance by setting an additional flag.
If we attempt to access an undefined flag an exception is raised (not shown).

```
import enum


class AvailableFlags(enum.Flag):
    flag1 = enum.auto()
    flag2 = enum.auto()


class FlagHelper:
    def __init__(self, cls, value = 0):
        self._cls = cls
        self._flags = self._cls(value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self._cls.__members__:
            return self.__class__(self._flags | getattr(self._cls, item))

        getattr(self._cls, item)  # Let attribute error pass through

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._flags.value)


class FuncFlags(FlagHelper):
    def __init__(self, value = 0):
        super().__init__(AvailableFlags, value)


def func(setup_flags: FuncFlags):
    print(setup_flags)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ff = FuncFlags()
    func(ff.flag1)
    func(ff.flag2)
    func(ff.flag1.flag2)
    func(ff)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps this helps?

```
import enum

class AvailableFlags(enum.Flag):
    flag1 = enum.auto()
    flag2 = enum.auto()

flag1, flag2 = AvailableFlag


def func(setup_flags: AvailableFlags):
    print(setup_flags)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func(flag1)
    func(flag2)
    func(flag1|flag2)
    func()
```

Comment: Sorry, i was misled. flag1 and flag2 are indeed distinct. Really interesting way to define aliases. Wasn't aware of that `enum` feature!